# What's causing my textures to look ribbed?

Tags: texturing

This seems like an easy problem to fix but I'm running out of ideas. Simply put, I'm trying to add this brick texture to my building, but in rendered view, the top of the building looks ribbed. Really don't like the way it looks. Any ideas on how to fix this? I'm using version 2.93 if that helps[image]

[image]

Comment: We need more information. Can you at least include a readable screen shot of your material node tree?

Comment: Are you using EEVEE?

Comment: Yes I'm using Eevee. I'll post another picture

Comment: I noticed that under the shading tab the texture isn't ribbed. Why is this?

Comment: What does the underlying geometry look like? Do the ribs correspond to faces in a subdivided cube? Are the normals correctly aligned?

Comment: providing blend file would help us...so we could effectively help you instead of guessing around and asking you question what it could be...

Comment: I don't know how to upload a .blend file

Comment: I think I figured out the problem. The sun light I put in was too low, and I think the ribbed look was the result of the sun light casting shadows of the trees on the building.